# Unable to insert contents into the database

Tags: c#, sql

I have created a sql server database in godaddy and created a table named property manually.i also successfuly connected my application to the database using connection string.But i am unable to insert any values to the table using my c# code 
Below is my C# code

```
string strQuery = "INSERT INTO property(name,email,phone,heading,description,location,image1,image2,image3,image4) VALUES('" + name + "','" + email + "','" + phone + "','" + title + "','" + description + "','" + district + "',@data,@data2,@data3,@data4);";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);


cmd.Parameters.Add("@data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@data2", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes2;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@data3", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes3;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@data4", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes4;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = con;
try
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    return true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
    return false;
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: What is "constr" in  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(); ? Can you get data of the database? Does only insert not work?

Comment: are you receiving any errors?

Comment: constr is connection string.there is no error but when i read data into a datatable it shows that datatable has zero rows

Comment: what exception it is throwing ?

Answer (score 0):

Parameterize your query and clean it up a bit. Hope this helps.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connection Info"))
{
    // Create your parameterized command.
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [property] (name, email, phone, heading, description, location, " +
                                    "                        image1, image2, image3, image4) VALUES " +
                                    "                       (@name, @email, @phone, @heading, @description, @location, " +
                                    "                        ,@image1,@image2,@image3,@image4)", con);
    using (cmd)
    {
        // Set your command type.
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        // Add your parameters.
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "nameParamHere");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", "emailParamHere");
        // and so on until you complete all params.

        // Execute your command.
        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) { };
    }
}
```

Try granting insert to your connection string "USER ID". See this link for more info...
http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-grant-revoke-privileges-roles.htm

```
GRANT INSERT 
ON [property] 
TO {user_name} 
[WITH GRANT OPTION];
```

Comment: thank you for trying to help me.but this code works perfectly in my local server

Comment: @python What is your connection string?

Comment: constr is my connection string

Comment: @python generalized connection string of course. Just wanting to see the idea of your constr initialization.

Comment: Data Source=countydata.db.12049298.hostedresource.com; Initial Catalog=countydata; User ID=user id; Password='password';

Comment: @python Have you checked your permissions? Does the user you are trying to insert with have that capability?

Comment: No, ihaven'nt checked i thought every database would have input and output funcions

Comment: i am using sql server 2012.is there any change in query for that

Comment: whatever user you have supplied in User ID needs to have insert permissions. I have updated my answer to show a grant query outline.

Comment: i am still unable to insert values please help me